# Xampp - MySQL stopped unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp, innodb

I have installed Xampp on windows, but I have not even done anything with a Database yet.  I have simply setup a vhost container so I can keep `mysite.local` and `localhost` separate.  I successfully ran the phpMyAdmin console once before I changed any configuration settings but there is nothing that clearly indicates what is going wrong.

I have tried the following:

- Deleting ibdata
- Changing to Port 3308
- I do not run MySQL outside of Xampp on Windows so there is nothing in services.msc to end.
- I have tried running mysqld.exe from `xampp/mysql/bin` and it did nothing
- Not posted anywhere but I tried un-commenting `bind-address` for both `::1` and `127.0.0.1` as well as the `skip-networking` even though I'm not exactly sure what they do.  This did nothing.
- Reinstalling XAMPP and starting completely over again.

### Other relevant information

Xampp is run in Administrator mode, although it had no affect when I run phpMyAdmin before making any vhost changes.

I did also self-sign an SSL certificate simply so I could have the `https` protocol and so I could remove a few warnings that fill up the Apache log each time you start and stop the server.  I'm not sure if I possibly have something configured wrong but with just Apache running everything works and there are no errors or warnings when starting the Apache module.

I have tried to reduce the code down to the bare minimum required to recreate the issue.  Not much.  Install Xampp and add a vhost I guess?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Xampp

```
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
[mysql]     Status change detected: running
[mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
[mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
[mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
[mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
[mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
[mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

### SQL Error Log

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
[Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
[Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
[Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
[Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
[Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
[Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 47134; transaction id 9
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\Xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
[Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200808 20:25:45
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

### HTTPD

```
ServerName localhost:80
ServerName mysite.local:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "D:/Xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/mysite.local />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

### HTTPD VHOST

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local.com
    ServerAlias mysite.local.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/mysite.local"
</VirtualHost>
```

### HTTPD SSL

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/Xampp/htdocs"
ServerName mysite.local:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "D:/Xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "D:/Xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "D:/Xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "D:/Xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I promise this is not a duplicate even though the title is.